# withMathJax format lost after reactive input changed

Tags: r, shiny, latex, reactive, uioutput

**Example Code:**

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  withMathJax(),
  tags$div(HTML("<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
                MathJax.Hub.Config({
                tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
                });
                </script>
                ")),

    sidebarPanel(sliderInput("k", "(k_{test})", value=2, min=1, max=3)),

    mainPanel(uiOutput("out"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$out <- renderUI({ paste("(k_{test}=)", input$k)}) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Here is my Problem:**
Initially, the app works fine. When changing the input on the slider, however, the output equation loses its format and I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
?withMathJax
```

says:

> It only needs to be called once in an app unless the content is
>   rendered after the page is loaded, e.g. via renderUI, in which case we
>   have to call it explicitly every time we write math expressions to the
>   output.

```
output$out <- renderUI({ 
  list(
    withMathJax(),
    paste("(k_{test}=)", input$k)
  )
})
```

should solve your problem